# The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided,

Tags: facebook

The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `fb:app_id` meta tag with the rest of your `og:` tags

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567890"/>
```

Comment: but what does the app_id mean? as I don't expect facebook requests people to provide "1234567890", this answer is not anyhow helpful.

Comment: ID of your Facebook application, you need to create one just to get an ID.

Answer (score 1):

It's better not to provide `fb:app_id`, but set it in url like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=123456789&display=popup&href=...
```

because it is less markedly..